# Error returning parameter from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developping a site and I using ajax to show some messages to the user, like if he inserted something in all inputs, if my database function worked fine, etc. But the problem is, when I return the string 'empty' from php to ajax, it works fine, but when I return the string 'success', my ajax doesn't work, it just redirect me to my php page and shows in the screen 'success'. What can be wrong?

My ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-enviar").click(function () {
            var action = $("#novo-artigo-form").attr("action");
            var form_data = {
                titulo: $("#titulo").val(),
                imagem: $('#imagem')[0].files[0],
                texto: $("#texto").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'success') {
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").removeClass("alert-danger alert-warning");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").addClass("alert alert-success");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").html("<p id='login-mensagem-sucesso'>Artigo adicionado!.</p>");
                    }
                    if (response == 'error') {
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").removeClass("alert-success alert-warning");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").html("<p id='login-mensagem-erro'>Houve um erro ao adicionar no banco.</p>");
                    }
                    if(response == 'errors'){
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").removeClass("alert-success alert-warning");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").html("<p id='login-mensagem-erro'>Houve um erro na imagem.</p>");
                    }
                    if(response == 'empty'){
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").removeClass("alert-success alert-danger");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").addClass("alert alert-warning");
                        $("#mensagem-artigo-novo").html("<p id='login-mensagem-aviso'>Preencha todos os campos.</p>");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

My php code:

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/banco/banco.php';
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$data = date('Y-m-d');
$texto = $_POST['texto'];

$nomeImagem = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$formato = strtolower(end(explode('.', $nomeImagem)));
$extensoes = array('.jpg', '.png');

if (empty($titulo) || empty($texto)) {
    echo 'empty';
} else if (inserirPublicacao($conexao, $titulo, $data, $imagem, $texto) == 1) {
    $id = ultimoId($conexao);
    $caminhoBanco = '/imagens/publicacoes/' . $id . '.' . $formato;
    $caminho = '../../imagens/publicacoes/' . $id . '.' . $formato;
    if (alterarCaminho($conexao, $caminhoBanco, $id) == 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($imagem, $caminho)) {
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'errors';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

So, in my php code, when my `titulo` and `texto` are empty, it shows in the screen a message saying that is empty. But when everything works, I am redirected to another screen that is my php file.. So what is wrong? Why only my 'empty' statement works?
Another strange thing is that if I change the 'success' to 'empty' it doesn't work too!

P.S.: All my div ids are right, so the problem isn't there.

Comment: First, use the event submit instead click. If the user presses "enter", your event is not fired but the form is send

Comment: Check spelling in .removeClass("alert-success alert-wraning");

Comment: @R3tep Ok, I will change in my code, but not in the question code. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @allu Thanks man, but this is only details

Comment: From where did you get $conexao variable that is used as a parameter in php inserirPublicacao method?

Comment: @netpork actually this variable only exists in my banco.php. But this is right because it is inserting into de database and uploading the image in my server